# Расположение JPanel внутри JMenuItem

Tags: java, swing

Как расположить `JPanel` в `JMenuItem` слева или справа (имеется в виду расположение относительно текста `JMenuItem`), а не по центру (прямо поверх текста), как это происходит автоматически?

Поясняю:

Есть обычный JMenuItem, созданный так:

```
new JMenuItem("menu item text")
```

Как положить JPanel слева или справа, а не по центру прямо поверх этого текста?

Comment: Пару раз прочитал вопрос - нече не понял, какой-то набор слов ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в двух предыдущих коментариях ответ на мой вопрос. прошу прощения, что в такой форме.

Answer (score 1):

Для размещения элемента является метод `SETBOUNDS();`, параметром которого является 4 целые числа: первые два X, Y - это координаты верхней левой точки элемента, другие два параметра - это высота и ширина элемента.

Корректно этот метод работает, при нулевой компоновке формы.

```
 Frame.GetContentpane (setLayout (null));
```

На счет `JMenuItem`, насколько я знаю в него помещается только текст, и никакие другие элементы. Чтобы разместить этот текст слева или справа, нужно просто использовать методы для форматирования текста.

Comment: В JMenuItem помещается не только текст, получилось положил внутрь JMenuItem нужные мне компоненты (JLabel с текстом и несколько JPanel).

Comment: так задача решена? пример решения можно?

Comment: protected JMenuItem createColorPanel(Vector colors, Action action) {
        JPanel jColorButton;
        int limit;
        JMenuItem panel = new JMenuItem(action);
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        JLabel jLabel = new JLabel(i18n.getMessage("colorsByCondition"));
        panel.add(jLabel, new GridBagConstraints(0,0,10,1,1,0,GridBagConstraints.WEST,GridBagConstraints.BOTH,new Insets(0,0,0,0),0,0));

if (colors != null && !colors.isEmpty()){
            if (colors.size() > 5)
                limit = 5;
            else
                limit = colors.size();

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
                jColorButton = new JPanel();
                jColorButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10, 10));
                jColorButton.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(10, 10));
            jColorButton.setBackground(((ConditionalColorAttribute) colors.get(i)).getColor());
                panel.add(jColorButton, new GridBagConstraints(i+10,0,1,1,0,0,GridBagConstraints.EAST,GridBagConstraints.NONE,new Insets(0,0,0,0),0,0));
            }
        }
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 20));
        return panel;
    }